# Using PHP/MySQL with Google Maps

Tags: php, mysql, database, google-maps, geocoding

I was able to solve my last problem. I currently find my self in a situation well over my head I think. I am implementing the google map into my website from google developers.

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3?hl=en-EN#createmap

Now here are the two things I am curious about. I now have the map on my site. I am able to manually search address for their geocode. I create fields in the table and add the name address, town, state, etc,. of each new business I want to list with a marker.

As of right now my map on my site works the same as on the google developers. The part specifically I am interested in changing is when you click one of the red or blue markers a pop up with the name and address appears. I would like to make the name of the business a link. OR if it would be easier create a field/column inside the table to be called 'url'. I have done do and was able to see the output of the 'url' field in xml format by calling the file directly. but it will not show up on the map. Any ideas? I am dead stuck and dieing inside until I get this figured out. Thanks!

Also If I create a list (excel format or something) of the address, names, etc, of each bueiness is there a way to search out all their geocodes at once rather than each one manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting to add a link to the company's website, you'll need to modify the following line:

```
var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
```

The variable html is being as the content of the InfoWindow.

Example:

```
var html = '<a href="' + link + '">' + name + '</a> <br/>' + address + '<br />Rating: ' + score;
```

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Oh um one more thing. If I want to add new fields to be displayed like say a rating/score and or a description what would I do I assume it would be equally as easy?

Comment: Wouldn't work for me that time. I updated my original post to include my code. Also thanks for your patience.

Comment: If i leave the  + description; on the end I no long see the marker. If i delete it i se the markers again.